# Why is there extra white space at the top of my html email?

Tags: html, html-email

I'm trying to write an HTML email. When I run it in Chrome it is at the top of the page, but when I send it in an email there is a lot of white space at the top. Also, it looks very different in yahoo mail and in gmail. Can somebody tell me why? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>


    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {border-collapse: collapse !important !important;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="margin-top:0 !important;margin-bottom:0 !important;margin-right:0 !important;margin-left:0 !important;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;background-color:#ffffff;" >
    <center style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;" >
        <div style="max-width:600px;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;" >
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
            <![endif]-->
            <table align="center" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;" >
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                        <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;width:100%;text-align:left;" >
                                    <p style="Margin:0;font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;Margin-bottom:10px;" >Your word for the day</p>
                                    <p style="Margin:0;font-size:14px;Margin-bottom:10px;" >Word in Tajik: Word in English</p>
                                    <p style="Margin:0;font-size:14px;Margin-bottom:10px;" >Part of speech: </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any css other than the inline styles?

Comment: No. I moved it all to inline.

Comment: It is not an easy task to get your html to look consistent across email services.  My advice would be to only use tables and very minimal css.

Comment: Email templates should only be in table base that's work fine

Comment: So remove the outer div? Or body tags? Head?

Comment: keep the head and body, remove the center and div tags

Comment: FYI, MS Outlook is one pain to support.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct but I would also remove the IE stuff

Comment: Tried removing the head and all outer tags so that table was the outer tag. That didn't work. Tried removing just the center and div tags. That didn't work. Still have a lot of white space at the top for both gmail and yahoo. And in gmail there is a lot of white space between rows. (I didn't post all of the rows in my code above.)

Comment: I tried removing all the IE stuff. That didn't help either.

Comment: Try removing the paragraph tags and replace with break tags. Not all email client support paragraph tags the same way.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with Gmail: a lot of blank space at the beginning of the email.

For me the solution was to **minify the content before body tag**. I minified the content using https://www.willpeavy.com/tools/minifier and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, Dude, you saved me.

Answer (score 2):

**Looks like you need more of a CSS reset for your email**. One rule isn't enough :(

Here is the reset I use in my own emails. This should eliminate the extra space at the top in *most* clients (Still gonna get a little space in Win Outlook, nothing we can do about that) and negate a few random breakages in clients.

The code is commented so you know what rules do what.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->

    <style>
        /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        /* What it does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin:0 !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

---

[Full code is on GitHub](https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus) if you want to dive deeper.

Comment: I tried Ted, but I still get a lot of white space on top. Wondering if it has anything to do with my Wordpress plugin "Email Subscribers & Newsletters".

Comment: Oh yea, for sure if there is any software in the middle that could be messing with the markup. Perhaps use a tool like https://litmus.com/scope/ to inspect the markup that's actually sent to the inbox.

Comment: My template works perfectly in a browser, but when I use some third party Mail Client, it messes the templates. So, I minified my codes,  and it starts working perfectly.